# Send List of bitmap in parcelable

Tags: android

Hello I need to send List from one activity to another, I found method in parcel
readTypedList amd write TypedList
I writethem like

```
     parcel.writeTypedList(busImages);
```

and try to call like

```
      in.readTypedList(busImages,Bitmap.Creator);
```

but there is error in second parametr Bitmap.Creator, Do i need create my own creator or how to solve this problem?
class code:

```
  public class ExtendBusModel extends BusModelParcelable {
private List<Bitmap> busImages;
private String Country;

public ExtendBusModel(BusModelParcelable model, List<Bitmap> busImages, String country) {
    super(model, model.getCountOfPlaces(),model.getTransportClass());
    this.busImages = busImages;
    Country = country;
}

protected ExtendBusModel(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    Log.d("read parsel buses", TestTags.TAG1);
   // in.readList(busImages,List.class.getClassLoader());
    in.readTypedList(busImages,Bitmap.Creator);
    Log.d("read parcel coutry",TestTags.TAG1);
    Country = in.readString();
    Log.d("done read",TestTags.TAG1);
    //  super(in);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    super.writeToParcel(parcel, i);
    //parcel.writeList(busImages);
    parcel.writeTypedList(busImages);
    parcel.writeString(Country);
}

public static final Creator<ExtendBusModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ExtendBusModel>() {

    @Override
    public ExtendBusModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ExtendBusModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ExtendBusModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ExtendBusModel[size];
    }
};

public List<Bitmap> getBusImages() {
    if(busImages == null)
        return new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    return busImages;
}

public void setBusImages(List<Bitmap> busImages) {
    this.busImages = busImages;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}
```

}

Comment: Please, post full class code which implements the `Parcalable`.

Comment: @HamidShatu I posted it

Comment: is `BusModelParcelable` implements `Parcelable` interface?

Comment: I have posted an answer...but its need to see your `BusModelParcelable` class...Can you please post it?

Comment: @HamidShatu then here will be a lot of code, It is not nessecary this class works correctly and problem is in List<Bitmap> .

Answer (score 0):

Write your `CREATOR` as below...this may be solve your problem.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public ExtendBusModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ExtendBusModel(in);
    }

    public ExtendBusModel[] newArray(int size) {
        new ExtendBusModel[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: parcel.writeParcelable(busImages,flags); Error in parcel canot be aplied